# Load page error in SWT Browser

Tags: java, macos, swt

I used SWT Browser in my Java project. I work on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6.

There is problem when I try to load page https://www.tradehub.net/ on OSX system, should be load panel to login but nothing happens - only gray background of page and error shows in console like below. In other pages everything is ok.

```
2016-10-13 12:05:53.026 java[26068:1126259] _createMenuRef called with existing principal MenuRef already associated with menu
2016-10-13 12:05:53.027 java[26068:1126259] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9341d4f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff95280f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff934844bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8fc6ac86 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _createMenuRef] + 62
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8fc6a5c5 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _instantiateCarbonMenu] + 140
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8fc68270 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 856
    6   libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000124e03e5a -[NSApplicationAWT finishLaunching] + 683
    7   libswt-pi-cocoa-4626.jnilib         0x00000001810dc6e9 Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_objc_1msgSendSuper__Lorg_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_objc_1super_2J + 153
    8   ???                                 0x000000010c553e64 0x0 + 4501880420
)
2016-10-13 12:05:56.844 java[26068:1126676] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
```

SWT library for OSX System - org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 in 4.6.1 version.

I compile my application to Windows system, used SWT - org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 in 4.6.1 version and there this page is loading fine (loaded panel show correct and there is no error).

What can cause this problem ?

Comment: This is likely a bug in SWT and you may want to [file a bug report](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php) (after making sure that nobody else already submitted this bug).

Comment: Ok I report this bug, when I fix this problem I will post an answer ;)